# SlackAPI - Include dialogs input and original message

Tags: slack-api, slack-dialog

I'm using SlackAPI views_open with trigger_id to open a dialog modal.
In that dialog modal user will input some information. My issue is I want to include this input and original message before submit.

Would anyone guide me how to do this?
I'm very appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After read Slack document I found the way, just push data into private_metadata for later use

https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/views